# ufw logs too much stuff, how can I disable that?

Tags: ubuntu, logs, ufw

I happen to find out that `syslog.1` takes 27 Gb and the logs in it have been inserted by the firewall ufw. How can I disable or reduce logging that much stuff into syslog by ufw?

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu's Community Help Wiki page on [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Logging) has information on toggling logging if you'd like to disable it completely. The [man page on UFW](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/ufw.8.html#logging) has much better information on it, which provides more advanced options for log levels.

The quick workaround is to use the command `ufw logging off` to eliminate ufw logging entirely (might or might not fulfill your wishes).

Comment: I'm guessing that running "ufw logging off" only works until next reboot (don't have a system available to test...)

Comment: @KolonUK, it seems to survive reboots. The option `LOGLEVEL=off` in `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` seems to not have an effect for some reason, even with a current version at the time of this comment.

Comment: I just installed ufw and the conf file has this comment: `# Please use the 'ufw' command to set the loglevel. Eg: 'ufw logging medium'.` This suggests we're not supposed to edit the `LOGLEVEL` setting directly.